# In CSS what is the difference between using ul#test and #test ul

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can someone shed some light on what the difference is between these two types of CSS declarations:

```
ul#test {
}

#test ul {
}
```

I have looked and cant seem to find the difference, but they act differently when I use them on a test page.  As far as I can tell they do the same thing, which is to associate the #test ID only with a UL tag that it is assigned to.  In actual use, though, when I use ul#test in my style sheet, the formatting works properly.  On the other hand, if I use #test ul it does not.

You can see what I am referring to here:

http://jsbin.com/awixib/2/edit#source

Does the ul#test method mean that the ID is assigned specifically to a UL tag and the  #test ul means that the UL is within another tag that is assigned the ID?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ul#test {
}
```

This one is applied to the `ul` whose id is `test`

```
#test ul {
}
```

this one applies to `ul` whose ancestor is an element with an id `test`